# App for editing files in my Dropbox?

Tags: iphone, applications, dropbox, emacs

My current setup is Dropbox with a directory called /Docs, in which I have my emacs .org outline files.

If you don't know about Emacs and org-mode, these files are plain text, just formatted with ** and so on for headings, however the extension is .org

I have tried Elements, however it would not let me view notes with the extension of .org

So essentially, I want to sync up notes between org-mode and an app on my iPhone 4, without using MobileOrg (which doesn't really sync as such).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**PlainText 2**](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/plaintext-2/id769101727?mt=8), it syncs with Dropbox (you can choose which folder to sync) and it let you choose which file extensions you want to sync.

Answer (score 1):

[Nebulous Lite](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nebulous-notes-lite/id392778235?mt=8) ([there's also a non-ad-supported version](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nebulous-notes-for-dropbox/id375006422?mt=8)) is a text editor for any type of file in Dropbox.  I frequently use it to edit plain text files.  I just tested it to sync and edit text files with a .org extension and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The best comparison of text editors for iOS is the one started by Brett Terpstra found here :-

http://brettterpstra.com/ios-text-editors/

Unfortunately org-mode support is not one of the fields but the only one I've ever heard of is MobileOrg that you've mentioned.

You might find this blog post on using a combination of other software to implement an org-mode workflow useful.

http://www.osomac.com/2013/10/07/ios-workflows-org-mode/

His idea of using [Drafts](http://agiletortoise.com/drafts/) and [Pythonista](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/index.html) to do org-mode work is a good one.

My recommendation to you would be to have a good look at [Editorial](http://omz-software.com/editorial/) as it is a good editor with a Python interpreter and automation system behind it. You could probably hack together some good org-mode stuff in that. It is written by the same person that wrote `Pythonista` mentioned in the blog post above.

Personally I find myself using `Drafts`, `Byword` and `Editorial` for different purposes and all three have no problem with Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice iPhone Text Editors comparison by the great Michael Tsai (author of SpamSieve among others).

[Comparing iPhone Text Editors, v4](http://mjtsai.com/blog/2011/07/18/comparing-iphone-text-editors-v4/). I can't post any conclusion he makes here, because he doesn't make much, other than that he's still sticking with [Notesy](http://notesy-app.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There is a very comprehensive review of IOS text editors with DropBox support here:

http://appadvice.com/appguides/show/dropbox-text-editors

Reviews are quite detailed and describe the pros, cons and costs.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone. In this case: which of the apps best fits the OPs needs?